# Auto Create PHP Scripts from a Mysql Database?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Is there any free site/software that can take a MYSQL database structure
and auto generate the html forms, and php code to insert, modify, and delete.

I used it a few years ago to quickly develop a prototype.

==========================

## **This worked for me below.** Nov.5th,2012

Update: using this: http://www.turningturnip.co.uk/free-mysql-php-generator/generator.php created this with this link: http://www.turningturnip.co.uk/free-mysql-php-generator/web-code-creator.php

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
`id` int(6) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`firstname` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
        `lastname` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
        `ssn` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
        PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
)
ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+crud

Comment: http://www.turningturnip.co.uk/free-mysql-php-generator/generator.php

Comment: I ended up using this generator above, because it creates your mysql table code for you:

Comment: This might be the link you need to get into it: http://www.turningturnip.co.uk/free-mysql-php-generator/web-code-creator.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That called CRUD and that is what almost every modern frameworks have.

Depending on your needs - you may choose:

- Symfony2 + Doctrine2 - it will give you very flexible codebase, but there would be some verbosities in code and it will be relatively hard to learn, however if you are making just some admin-like interface I don't think you need such complex framework.
- Symfony2 + Propel2 - almost the same as above, but Propel implements Active Record pattern, when Doctrine is Data Mapper.
- Yii - also requires some learning, but very simpler than Symfony2.
- CakePHP - also can generate you CRUD (aka scaffolding) using `bake` command.
- Codeigniter - very simple php framework (actually the simplest), crud can be generated via GroceryCrud.

All this frameworks (or ORM's integrated in them) can do database reverse engineering (generate models from database) and create crud from models. But these are not all the tools that exist.

Also you can have look at phpmyadmin (or any other tool for working with database).

Answer (score 1):

This might fit the bill, it's based on CodeIgniter and is well documented:

http://www.grocerycrud.com/